# Apache Apex - Custom written Kafka Offset Manager

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hadoop-yarn, kafka-consumer-api, apache-apex

If I write my own implementation of OffsetManager for kafka input operator,

How should I configure kafka input operator to use my custom build offset manager ? I know about the property “OffsetManager”, But can someone please share some working example of how to set the offset manager ?

Thanks a lot.